# How to make ul padding-right being respected by list items when dynamically set (inside a timeout)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, settimeout

The problem I am facing is when trying to set the padding-right property of a  element, inside a code running in a setTimeout, the **li** elements inside it are not properly resized.
The problem does not occur (or at least very seldom) when I am not inside a setTimeout.

Can someone confirm this is a **webkit bug** or otherwise point to a solution?

I was able to reproduce it in Chrome and Safari.

I have created 3 scenarios (please use Chrome and Safari to test):

1. The ul with padding-right in static css - obviously works http://jsbin.com/ufifos/5/edit
2. The ul with padding-right set in js code not inside setTimeout - works (most of the times) see jsbin.com/ekazow/1/edit
3. The ul with padding-right set in js code inside a setTimeout - NOT WORKING properly http://jsbin.com/uzorux/1/edit

The padding-right is set, but the **li** elements are not repainted correctly. A browser resize (or a few resizes) fixes it.

Basically the code is

```
setTimeout(function(){

    document.getElementById('container').style.paddingRight = '20px';

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Getting the same problem in safari 5.1 but working in IE9 and FF16

Comment: Yes, any webkit based browser seems to have this problem. Using divs instead of ul and li elements behaves exactly the same. Have tried to use the requestAnimationFrame API, but the problem persists. Seems to be a problem with async DOM updating. I have filled a bug in the webkit bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this rule:

```
li {
   width: 100%;
}
```

It is not in the first "working" test.  Remove it and it should work fine.  You might need to set `display: block` on the li as well.

Comment: Have you tested it? This is definitely not the problem.